# What is the pin to light up colon in Basys 2?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, display, 7segmentdisplay

I am trying to make a clock in a [Basys2 board](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?NavPath=2,400,790&Prod=BASYS2) but I can't find in documentation the pin to light up the colon of the 7segment display. Where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the colon lights up.

From reading the [schematic](https://www.digilentinc.com/Data/Products/BASYS2/Basys2_sch.pdf), in page 2 you can see that there are 12 wires, none of which seem to drive the colon (there are wires CA..CG for the segments, DP for the decimal point and AN0..AN3 for multiplexing the displays).

Looking at the [datasheet of the 7-segment display](http://www.oasistek.com.tw/pdf/TOF-2481AMG-N.pdf), does not have a way to light up the colon, either.

I worked once with a similar board (Nexys3) and I don't remember the colon lighting up.

Comment: But it has the colon carved in the 7seg display. How come?

Comment: @ErinAvllazagaj I don't know. Maybe the display's manufacturer uses the same packaging for another display that has the colon, for example.